Unexpected Animation in iOS 17.5: How to Disable It
Previously, the following code would not yield any animation:
@IBAction func deleteButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    exitEditMode()
}

private func exitEditMode() {
    addButton.isHidden = false
    labelView.isHidden = false
    
    touchableCircleView.isHidden = true
    doneButton.isHidden = true
    deleteButton.isHidden = true
    textField.isHidden = true
    
    doneButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark"), for: .normal)
    
    textField.text = nil
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

However, when running the code on an actual device with iOS 17.5, it results in an animation.
To avoid the animation, you need to wrap the call to exitEditMode() within UIView.performWithoutAnimation, as shown below:
@IBAction func deleteButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        exitEditMode()
    }
}

I am unable to reproduce this issue in the Simulator, possibly because it only supports up to iOS 17. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Animation
I first tap on "Add label", then I tap on the "X" button. Tapping on "X" button will execute deleteButtonClicked. The UI is implemented using UICollectionView.


It would be great if you could record a short screenshot video.

It would be great if you could give an actual [mcve] we can run. You haven't done that; you haven't even bothered to tell us what animates.

Animation included.

You still haven't explained how to reproduce this. What is that column of items? Is it a table view? Are those table view cells?
